# Websockets: multiple responses from NodeJS websocket server to C# client with WebSocketSharp fro

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket

In NodeJS I've created a small testserver which sends a response when it received a message. When I try to send a message from my C# client side, no answer is received back. After research I noticed that it has to do with the websocket connection which is probably closed. This is what I want to achieve:

1. I click a button (`TrySocket`) I send a message to the server, and receive the answer.
2. After that on the server there is polling action to an api which takes about 10 seconds. After receiving the data from that api, I want to send it to my client through the same websocket connection.

This is my C# code so far.

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace test_CS
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void TrySocket(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
            ws.OnOpen += (senders, d) =>
            {
                Response.Write("CONNECTED<br />");
            };
            ws.OnMessage += (senders, d) =>
            {
                Response.Write(d.Data);
            };
            ws.OnClose += (senders, d) =>
            {
                Response.Write("DISCONNECTED<br />");
            };

            ws.Connect();
            ws.Send("test message 1");
            ws.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection will close after sending "test message 1". Why don't you close it after getting a message from server. i.e.

```
protected void TrySocket(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    ws.OnOpen += (senders, d) =>
    {
        Response.Write("CONNECTED<br />");
    };
    ws.OnMessage += (senders, d) =>
    {
        Response.Write(d.Data);
        // if message is close
        //  ws.Close(); close connection
    };
    ws.OnClose += (senders, d) =>
    {
        Response.Write("DISCONNECTED<br />");
    };

    ws.Connect();
    ws.Send("test message 1");
    //ws.Close(); // Remove this.it causes you client to close after sending a message.
   
}
```

This client doent no run.

```
using System;    
using System.Net;    
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading;    


namespace node_pipe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
        protected void TrySocket(object sender, EventArgs e){
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
        ws.OnOpen += (senders, d) =>
        {
            Response.Write("CONNECTED<br />");
        };
        ws.OnMessage += (senders, d) =>
        {
            Response.Write(d.Data);
            // if message is close
            //  ws.Close(); close connection
        };
        ws.OnClose += (senders, d) =>
        {
            Response.Write("DISCONNECTED<br />");
        };

        ws.Connect();
        ws.Send("test message 1");
    //ws.Close(); // Remove this.it causes you client to close after sending a message.
   
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that one too, but the problem is that I even don't receive an answer from the NodeJS server. If I put in ```System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);``` I receive everything back, but all at once after 10 seconds. I want to send to the NodeJS server and receive a response and the wait for the second response to be sent from the NodeJS server.

Comment: Can you also add the node code. And is this the only function that gets called on button click?

Comment: See the above answer, it was too long to be in this comment section.

Comment: Any new insights kg99?

Comment: Can you post a working c# client code so I can test.

Comment: The working C# client code is in my initial post. The NodeJS code is in my second post.

Comment: Including the libraries that you call. I keep getting "'WebSocket' does not contain a definition for 'OnOpen' and no accessible extension method 'OnOpen' accepting a first argument of type 'WebSocket' could be found " and I havent used c# in forever.

Comment: It's not a Windows Application, but a Web applicatio, see my edit of my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is my Node code. I simulated the api call with a `setTimeout`
Only the function `TrySocket`is called on the C# side.

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message)
        if (message == 'test message 1') {
            ws.send('this is answer 1<br />');
            //API call simulation with timeout
            setTimeout(() => {
                ws.send('2nd answer<br />');
            }, 3000);
        }
    }) 
})

server.listen(8080, function listening() {
    console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port)
})
```